# Spring security 5 and Bootstrap - no content is displayed

Tags: jquery, html, spring, spring-security

I want to make custom login page. However, when I enable spring security, no content is displayed (css and js are loaded though).

**WebSecurity Config**

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/login**").permitAll()
.and()
.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
.and()
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/loginAction").permitAll()
.and()
.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
.and()
.csrf().disable();}
```

With the security enabled I can't see any of the content from my jsp page.
It looks like this:
[image]

While it should look like this:
[image]

Background is an image.

In my jsp login page I include resources like:

```
<link href='<spring:url value="/resources/css/animate.css"/>' rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='<spring:url value="/resources/css/icomoon.css"/>' rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='<spring:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css"/>' rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='<spring:url value="/resources/css/superfish.css"/>' rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='<spring:url value="/resources/css/style.css"/>' rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:url value="/resources/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"/>'></script>




<script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery.min.js"/>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"/>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"/>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:url value="/resources/js/jquery.stellar.min.js"/>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:url value="/resources/js/hoverIntent.js"/>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='<spring:url value="/resources/js/superfish.js"/>'></script>
```

[image: Console]

[image: Resources]

[image: Network]

**Div that isn't displayed:**

```
        <div class="fh5co-hero">
        <div class="fh5co-overlay"></div>
        <div class="fh5co-cover" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" style="background-image: url('resources/images/home-image.jpg');">
            <div class="desc animate-box">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <h2>Fitness &amp; Health <br>is a <b>Mentality</b></h2>
                            <p><span>Start your journey<i class="icon-heart3"></i></span></p>
                            <span><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Login</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention CSS is loaded, yet the actual and expected screens differ in background. Look at the network tab in chrome inspector or firebug. Are all static resources (including images) loaded? Do any requests fail with authorization error?

Comment: I've changed the path to img and it's okay now. But the content still isn't loaded. At network tab in chrome inspector all resources have status 200. No errors in console also.

Comment: It’s okay but the content isn’t loaded?

Comment: I mean, the background image is ok now, but I can't display the content. I've added more images to the first post.